# How to customize chapter heading style?

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I have customized the default chapter style like below. The chapter number font is `Garamond` number font, whereas  the main text is `Times` font.

[image]

The codes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16, 45}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{mdugm} %Garamond
\usepackage[ ]{titlesec}  %
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  { \normalsize \huge  \color{black}}
  {\flushright \normalsize \color{RoyalRed} \MakeUppercase { \chaptertitlename } \hspace{1 ex} { \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \color{RoyalRed} \sffamily  \thechapter }} {10 pt}{\huge}  
  \begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
...
bla bla
...
\chapter{State of the art}
...
bla bla
...
\end{document}
```

So how to set the chapter title `state of art` as bold font?

Comment: There is *no* "Garamond sans" font. Redefining `\sfdefault` to `mdugm` has very little sense. And it has little sense having Times as main font and Garamond for the chapter numbers as well.

Comment: Well, I prefer `Garamond` number fonts to The Times' :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `{\bfseries\huge}` at the end:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  { \normalsize \huge  \color{black}}
  {\flushright \normalsize \color{RoyalRed} \MakeUppercase { \chaptertitlename \hspace{1 ex} }  { \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont \color{RoyalRed} \sffamily  \thechapter }} {10 pt}{\bfseries\huge}
```

## Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16, 45}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalsize \huge  \color{black}}%
  {\flushright\normalsize \color{RoyalRed}%
   \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\hspace{1ex}%
   {\fontfamily{mdugm}\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}}%
  {10 pt}%
  {\bfseries\huge}%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
...
bla bla
...
\chapter{State of the art}
...
bla bla
...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. so the last option defines the chapter title font  and size.

Comment: There are many spurious spaces in your code; also, why `\hspace{1ex}` in the argument of `\MakeUppercase`? I don't see why redefining `\sfdefault`; it suffices to say `\fontfamily{mdugm}` before `\fontsize{60}{60}`. Redefining `\sfdefault` to point to a serif font is quite strange, isn't it?

Comment: @egreg Yes, I was too focused to the problem and forgot to see those. Thank you. Hope now there aren't any more spurious spaces.

Comment: @egreg the reason why I set `\hspace{1ex}` is that `CHAPTER` looks too small when it's close to the Large Number.

Comment: @KOF There's nothing bad in using `\hspace` for separating the two parts. Just try various values until you're satisfied; for example `\hspace{2em}` (not `ex`, which makes little sense for horizontal lengths). Just don't put it in the argument to `\MakeUppercase`. Its place is outside it.