# Customizing chapter style with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, chapters, titlesec

How can I customize chapter style like below picture?
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to customize chapter heading style?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94729/5764); [Customizing Chapter style in `scrbook`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150923/5764)...

Comment: ...and what about using something from your previous question? [customizing part style with Tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159551/5764)

Comment: especially given your previous questions that Werner linked to, you need to show *some effort*

Comment: –1: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One possibility, using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and the [`epigraph`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epigraph) package; the rounded corner rectangle on top was produced using the pgf library `qrr.shapes.openrectangle` written by **Qrrbrbirlbel** in [`his answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140868/3954) to [Tikz shape similar to rectangle with selective drawing of borders](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140842/3954) (the link to the library can be found in the answer linked):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepgflibrary{qrr.shapes.openrectangle}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\tikzset{
mynode/.style={
  rounded corners=30pt,
  shape=open rectangle,
  open rectangle fill=myblueii,
  open rectangle sides=#1,
  }
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[
    anchor=west,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    text width=\paperwidth,
    xshift=-\the\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
    outer sep=0pt,
    fill=myblueiii] (titlerect) {};
  \node[
    anchor=south west,
    xshift=2cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at ([yshift=5pt]titlerect.south west) {\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont#1};
  \node[
    mynode=nw,
    anchor=south east,
    fill=myblueii,
    inner xsep=1.5cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    font=\color{white},
    minimum height=30pt] 
    at (current page.east|-titlerect.north)
     {\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[
    anchor=west,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    text width=\paperwidth,
    xshift=-\the\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
    outer sep=0pt,
    fill=myblueiii] (titlerect) {};
  \node[
    anchor=south west,
    xshift=2cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at (titlerect.south west) {\Huge#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-20pt}{60pt}

\setlength\beforeepigraphskip{1.5\baselineskip}
\setlength\afterepigraphskip{2\baselineskip}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{6.8cm}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\large}
\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}

\let\oldepigraph\epigraph \renewcommand\epigraph[2]{%
  \oldepigraph{\color{mybluei}\itshape #1}{#2}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{From the Ground Up!}
\epigraph{In theory there is no difference \\ between theory and practice. \\ In practice there is.}{Lawrence ``Yogui'' Berra,1925 \\ New York Yankees baseball player}
\chapter*{A test unnumbered chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 very nice! It might be nice to make the `epigraph` command format automatically, perhaps using `\let\oldepigraph\epigraph\renewcommand{\epigraph}[2]{\oldepigraph{\color{mybluei}\itshape #1}{#2}}`

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks! You're right about `\epigraph`; I've incorporated the suggestion to my answer.

Comment: You love doing chapter designs right? Looks gr8 by the way. I will study your code to make some improvements on my own.

Comment: @azetina Thanks. You're right, I can't resist a question about sectional units design :-)

Comment: i wrote a tikz code for upper right rounded corner box beacause i dont want to use \usepgflibrary{qrr.shapes.openrectangle}

Comment: @Jalil Great! Yes, using your method you can avoid using the library. Well done!

Comment: For network stumblers, to use `\usepgflibrary{qrr.shapes.openrectangle}` check http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187193/how-to-install-tikz-pgf-libraries

Comment: @GonzaloMedina please i use this but i have an error message: Command \widering already defined

Answer (score 3):

'I wrote a *tikz* code for upper right rounded corner box because i don't want to use

```
\usepgflibrary{qrr.shapes.openrectangle}
```

this is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,backgrounds}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}

\newcommand{\newtab}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=2mm,text=white] (#1) {#2};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \draw[fill=mybluei] 
        ($ (#1.north east) $) 
        --($ (#1.north west) $)
        to[out=180,in=90]  ([xshift=-1cm]$(#1.south west) $)
          -- ($ (#1.south east) $)
          -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}% 
}

\begin{document}
\newtab{test}{CHAPTER 1}
\newtab{test}{This is another test} 
\newtab{test}{This is yet another test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. To avoid extra (two possibly undesired blank spaces) add `%` just after the opening brace in the definition, as in `\newcommand{\newtab}[2]{%` and after `\end{tikzpicture}`, as in `\end{tikzpicture}%`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, when the font size is larger in the box, then we have a box with larger height. I want to calculate the height of the box to obtain radius of circle precisely. I used "let" and "in" tikz commands: ` let \p= ($ (#1.north) - (#1.south) $) in arc(90,180,{\veclin(\x,\y)}`  but i countered with an error.

Comment: You can measure the height + depth of a string using some lengths and `\settoheight` and `\settodepth`: \newlength\StrHt
\newlength\StrDp
\settoheight\StrHt{\Huge Abcp}
\settodepth\StrDp{\Huge Abcp}
\addtolength\StrHt{\StrDp}`; after this, `\StrHt` has the total height (height+depth) of the string Abcp in `\Huge` size. If you have additional doubts, please consider opening a fresh new question.