# Custom chapter style with Tikz and the report class

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I'm trying to use the same procedure than [Customizing chapter style with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160324/14800), for the report class and twoside printing.

However for even pages i'm having an unespected behavior (see Fig 2). While for odd pages i'm not having problems (see Fig 1).

**Figure 1**
[image: Fig1]

**Figure 2**
[image: Fig2]

I read in the documentation for titlesec one could use the extra option `\titleformat{name=\chapter,page=even/odd}` for even or odd pages, however when i compile a simpler version of the code the color boxes are not shown in the pdf.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepgflibrary{qrr.shapes.openrectangle}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\tikzset{
mynode/.style={
  rounded corners=30pt,
  shape=open rectangle,
  open rectangle fill=myblueii,
  open rectangle sides=#1,
  }
}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,page=even}[display]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[
    anchor=west,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    text width=\paperwidth,
    xshift=-\the\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
    outer sep=0pt,
    fill=myblueiii] (titlerect) {};
  \node[
    anchor=south west,
    xshift=2cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at ([yshift=5pt]titlerect.south west) {\huge #1};
  \node[
    mynode=nw,
    anchor=south east,
    fill=myblueii,
    inner xsep=1.5cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    font=\color{white},
    minimum height=30pt] 
    at (current page.east|-titlerect.north)
     {\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,page=odd}[display]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[
    anchor=west,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    text width=\paperwidth,
    xshift=-\the\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
    outer sep=0pt,
    fill=myblueiii] (titlerect) {};
  \node[
    anchor=south west,
    xshift=2cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at ([yshift=5pt]titlerect.south west) {\huge #1};
  \node[
    mynode=nw,
    anchor=south east,
    fill=myblueii,
    inner xsep=1.5cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    font=\color{white},
    minimum height=30pt] 
    at (current page.east|-titlerect.north)
     {\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {\huge #1}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-20pt}{60pt}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter odd}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{Chapter even}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Numberless chapter}

\end{document}
```

How can i solve this problem?.

Comment: I have the same problem: [Custom chapter style with tcolorbox in twoside printing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341889/custom-chapter-style-with-tcolorbox-in-twoside-printing) Can you help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've noticed a similar problem to that solution, and managed to come up with the following alternative (my [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) skills is not that great):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}% Loads tikz
\usepgflibrary{qrr.shapes.openrectangle}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\tikzset{
mynode/.style = {
  rounded corners = 30pt,
  shape=open rectangle,
  open rectangle fill = myblueii,
  open rectangle sides = #1,
  }
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[
    anchor = west,
    rectangle,
    minimum height = 4cm,
    ] 
    (titlerect) {};
  \fill[color = myblueiii] ([xshift = -1cm]current page.west|-titlerect.south) rectangle (current page.east|-titlerect.north);
  \node[
    anchor = south west,
    xshift = -1cm,
    text width = \textwidth] 
    at ([yshift = 5pt]titlerect.south west) {\huge #1};
  \node[
    mynode = nw,
    anchor = south east,
    fill = myblueii,
    inner xsep = 1.5cm,
    outer sep = 0pt,
    font = \color{white},
    minimum height = 30pt] 
    at (current page.east|-titlerect.north)
     {\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter};%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\titleformat{name = \chapter, numberless}[display]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[
    anchor = west,
    rectangle,
    minimum height = 4cm,
    ] 
    (titlerect) {};
  \fill[color = myblueiii] ([xshift = -1cm]current page.west|-titlerect.south) rectangle (current page.east|-titlerect.north);
  \node[
    anchor = south west,
    xshift = -1cm,
    text width = \textwidth] 
    at ([yshift = 5pt]titlerect.south west) {\huge #1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-20pt}{60pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter odd}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{Chapter even}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Numberless chapter}

\end{document}
```

I'm using [`tikzpagenodes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) to tap into the page boundary when setting the coloured boxes, rather than shifting them around manually.

Comment: Amazing @Werner Thanks. By the way, if you upload just the Tikz package the result is the same.