# Custom chapter style with tcolorbox in twoside printing

Tags: chapters, tcolorbox

I'm trying to use the same procedure than [chapter style with tcolorbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254318/chapter-style-with-tcolorbox), for the book class and twoside printing.

But I have the same problem in [Custom chapter style with Tikz and the report class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178569/custom-chapter-style-with-tikz-and-the-report-class).

It's working perfectly with odd pages. However for even pages I'm having an unexpected behavior: you can see that the blue strip stops before the side of the page.

Could you help me fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: would appreciate your help to @Gonzalo Medina, [link] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) In the code you refer to, the length `\oddsidemargin` si used. You should try with `\evensidemargin` when the chapter starts on an even page. (See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6193/64454) for even/odd differentiation)

Comment: Note also that `@`-pings only works for people who have either commented or edited the post, so Gonzalo will not be notified of that comment. (And as you can see from his profile, he hasn't been active for over a year.)

Comment: Just add option `toggle enlargement=evenpage` inside both `tcolorbox` declarations and margins will automatically adapt to even pages.