# I can not modify the chapter in latex

Tags: graphics, chapters, titlesec

Sorry for my English.
Hello, I want to get something like this:

[image: http://img110.xooimage.com/files/5/7/6/lpic-1-linux-prof...gina_059-4751149.jpg]

Latex My level is not so high to do so. I tried to do it with the following code, but not sure it will help some.

He had thought titlesec modify the chapter and table of contents with minitoc, but are incompatible.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{50pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}

\begin{document}
%\dominitoc[n]\nomtcrule
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Prueba}
\rule{\linewidth}{1mm}
%\minitoc
\section{otra prueba}
\subsection{probando subseccion}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look the answers given at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160320/customizing-chapter-style-with-tikz which asks almost the same question. And http://texblog.net/latex-archive/uncategorized/fancy-chapter-tikz/ is another example.

Comment: BTW, you can also use tikz to include and arrange photos, either using \includegraphics in a node or with a pgf style.